# Java - Get all the implementations of an interface available in client package

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, reflection, interface

I am developing one task scheduler which triggers the tasks in parallel using executor service. I want to make my task scheduler as generic and no code change/less code change in scheduler code base whenever any new type of task is added.

My tasks (mostly client package) can be of any type which basically just accepts particular request and execute the tasks.

To do this I am exposing interface (say ITask) which must be implemented by tasks (which will be on some other app/package) and that will be having one implementation method say example

```
doTask(IRequest request);
```

So the use case is if any clients who wants to trigger their job using my scheduler framework/API, just **need to add my package in their dependency** and rest (those are, getting the list of task classes which implements ITask > schedule it using executor service > retry failed tasks > finally provide the entire tasks status) should be taken care by my schedular API.

What is the optimal way to do this. I am thinking of solution how Junit gets its @Test methods (based on annotation) of client whoever adds Junit dependency in his package, similarly I want get classes based on interface.

Answer (score 2):

You have tagged this question with Spring, but you don't mention anywhere in the question that you are using the Spring framework. This answer makes a few assumptions:

1. You are using Spring Framework
2. The implementations of your desired interface have been configured as Spring Beans

If you get access to the ApplicationContext (see the interface ApplicationContextAware), you can use it to look up Spring beans of a certain type. It would look something like this:

```
Map<String, ITask> beans = appContext.getBeansOfType(ITask.class);
```

This method returns a map with the key being the bean identifier and the value being the instance of the bean itself. From there, you could loop through the values and add them to your job scheduler.

**Alternatively**

If you do not want the requirement of having to configure each ITask implementation as a Spring bean, you could use Spring's `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` (a mouthful, I know).

This is a nifty tool that allows you to scan base packages to find bean "candidates". However, in your case, you could use it to find ITask candidates. Clients to your library could configure the base scan packages which you would use to scan:

```
private String configuredListOfBasePackages;

public void someMethod () {
    ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
    scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(ITask.class));
    Set<BeanDefinition> iTaskCandidates = scanner.findCandidateComponents(configuredListOfBasePackages);
    // do stuff with the bean definitions
}
```

This method is obviously a bit more dangerous as it require you to be able to construct a new instance of every candidate you find. As such, this is not the ideal solution.

Comment: Thank you @rmlan. As of now I have not included spring. My code is in core java. If there is any alternative to do it in java without using spring, I would prefer that, since adding spring results in huge dependency. If there is no other option then i'll consider suing spring and also I need to ask my clients to declare beans for each of the ITask implementation.

Comment: Why did you tag the question Spring then?

Comment: I came across with few posts where I saw solutions with spring. My fault that I have not mentioned what kind of solution I am looking for.